# What is the availability logic for "Edit tags" link?

Tags: support, tags, questions

I have noticed that the "`Edit tags`" option/link is not available on some SO questions.

What is its availability rules?

Comment: Assuming you have sufficient rep, it will not be available if there is an open edit-suggestion on the post.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - In such cases there should be a number in parenthesis on the main `Edit` button, right?

Comment: Correct; do you need to clarify your question?

Comment: Some kinds of question locks disable edit tags too. Those questions would have a lock banner in place.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Yes, I might need to. I did not want to provide links so not to trigger the *meta effect*.  I think limited screen capture would help.

Comment: In addition, the "Edit tags" link will not be shown after the post is refreshed through some in-page actions (e.g., after an in-page refresh from an edit). You can demonstrate this by running `StackExchange.realtime.reloadPosts([427534])` in this question's browser console. IIRC, this is due to an inconsistency in the HTML structure provided through one or more of the SE-internal endpoints compared to the HTML structure when the page is originally served. This appears to be due to SE not following DRY for the rendering in different places, then making changes in one place, but not others.